# how to make a phone call from non activity?

Tags: java, android

This code works perfectly in activity, but when I use it in class it's not working.Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

```
Public class Example
{
    Intent callIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+"0554515514"));      
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Comment: Its not working means ? did you passed context ?

Comment: can you show code that is working as well?

Comment: You need to send the context to the class @Nadav

Comment: this class is trigered by an sms call and should initiate a phone call to a defined number but the issue is that the phone cal is not started.

Comment: "this class is trigered by an sms call" -- that is not a good idea. You do not know what the user is doing at the time. Interrupting the user by placing a phone call (and bringing up the in-call screen, etc.) has a chance of irritating the user.

Comment: This is a hidden application and interfering with what the user is doing is not a concern for now.I would like to understand why there is no call assuming the phone is in idle mode.

Comment: Note that there are several compiler errors in your example code. Please edit it to fix the errors. Also show how you expect this non-activity class to be used.

Comment: I want to show you the class,but It tells me that the comment is too long.How can I add this code here?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can send the `context` that is necessary to the class, and use it with the method `startActivity()` to open the Intent.

If you have a class that is not an `Activity` you can send the context via the constructor of the class.

```
private Context context;

  public myClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

  }
```

Then use this context to open the intent:

```
 public makeCall(){
    Intent callIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+"0554515514"));        
     context.startActivity(callIntent);
  }
```

Comment: I need the phone call to initate  when a specific message has recevied, without any activity.

Comment: @Nadav Where are you getting it then, a BroadcastReceiver?  In that case, the Receiver is passed a Context you can use.  A Service?  Then use the Service, which is also a Context.  In Android, all running code is associated with a Context at some level

Comment: I want to show you the class,but  It tells me that the comment is too long.How can I add this code here?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to communicate with some Activity from a non application class, simply take help of Interface as a communicator between your calling Class and Activity.

Example

```
interface Communicator{
void startCall();
}

Public class Example{
    public void someMethodToBeCalled(){
    Communicator communicator = new MainActivity();
    communicator.startCall();
    }
}

class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements Communicator{

    void startCall() {
    Intent callIntent= new Intent 
    (Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+"0554515514"));        
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

Observe that while making instance of Communicator class, you should do,

```
Communicator communicator = new MainActivity();
```

As you are implementing startCall() in Activity, communicator.startCall() will trigger MainActivity's startCall method.